# Use more than one post meta inside the loop

Tags: wordpress

I have custom meta st_date and end_date

I want to select the post with both of these conditions are true for :

> 1- end_date = "some date"
>
> 2- st_date = "some date"
>
> 3-Also I need it to select by title
>
> 4-Then used the result inside the WordPress loop.

```
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php get_template_part('loop'); ?> //etc..
```

Here is my draft code:

```
$st_date_s = 'something';
$end_date_s = 'something';
$pageposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_title'      => 'something'
        'post_type'      => 'something',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                array( 'key' => 'st_date', 'value' => $st_date_s, 'compare' => '=' ), 
                array( 'key' => 'end_date', 'value' => $end_date_s, 'compare' => '=' )
            )       
        ),  
    )
);
?>
<?php global $site_url;
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>
<?php else : ?>//etc..
```

Also why 'post_title'=> doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `relation` argument, and have one-too-many `array()`s. Since you want both conditions to be true, you should use `AND`:

```
...

    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 'key' => 'st_date', 'value' => $st_date_s, 'compare' => '=' ), 
        array( 'key' => 'end_date', 'value' => $end_date_s, 'compare' => '=' ),
    ),  

...
```

Read more about [custom field parameters in the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Comment: I removed the extra array and used 'relation' => 'AND'.

Comment: yes but 'post_title' => does not work yet and I am still testing the rest of your solution

Comment: Ah, there's no `post_title` parameter available...But you can use [get_page_by_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) to get the post ID and pass it to the object that way.